# Average insert time for a table in SQL Server historically

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Is there a way to retrieve the info on what was the average (or better a distribution) insert time into a given table in SQL Server up to the current point in time?

e.g. inserting into 'employees' took on average 1 millisecond per record.

I'm talking about historical data here e.g. over the last year, not what I can get for specific queries when profiling.

Comment: You have the [dynamic management views and functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188754.aspx).  But most of the statistics captured here are lost each time the SQL Server restarts.  As far as I know SQL Server doesn't log this stuff out of the box.  Just thinking, you might have more luck transferring this question over to [Stack DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You should also check plan cache. From there you can calculate the average duration per statement, and assuming you're not inserting into the table using a lot of different statements (and your queries are parametrized) you should get quite good results.

Here's one example how to query the DMVs:

```
select top 100
SUBSTRING(t.text, (s.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
  ((CASE s.statement_end_offset
  WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(t.text)
  ELSE s.statement_end_offset
  END - s.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) as statement_text,
t.text,
s.total_logical_reads, s.total_logical_reads / s.execution_count as avg_logical_reads,
s.total_worker_time, s.total_worker_time / s.execution_count as avg_worker_time,
s.execution_count,
creation_time,
last_execution_time
--,cast(p.query_plan as xml) as query_plan
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats s
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text (sql_handle) t
--cross apply sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan (plan_handle, statement_start_offset, statement_end_offset) p
order by s.execution_count desc
```

The part commented out is for query plans.

Comment: that works up until the sql server service is recycled.  As user stated, wants to go back a year.

Comment: Yes this definitely shows only up till the plan is in cache, which means it can be dropped at any point if it's not being used (or more cache is needed for others)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Profiler is not accurate, also it is marked deprecated starting SQL 2012.

Best tools for caturing performance-related data is extended events or perfmon.  Don't think perfmon will give you object level performance, but it will tell you if you have bottlenecks at IO level.  You will need to enable these tools/features for data collection, so if it hasn't been enabled already, then getting historical data is probably not possible.